# Having trouble getting pandas onto Slackware 14

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pandas, slackware

I've been trying to install python-pandas, got an error message:

```
install requires: 'python-dateutil < 2','numpy'
$ pip install 'python-dateutil < 2' 'numpy'
```

I'm new to slackware (like the steep learning curve), so I got the binaries from various websites, unpacked the files but I still keep getting this message. I do have a new directory titled 'usr' in my Downloads directory. I'm assuming that's supposed to go in the python directory but I'm not completely sure. Just lookin' for a little advice. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try installing numpy and python-dateutil using pip /easy_install and then again try and install Pandas?

Comment: My problem was not having pip installed...had to do a few tasks to get that done. But it's all working now. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just add the answer and mark as closed

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not having pip installed...had to do a few tasks to get that done. But it's all working now.